# How to get sane working with old Agfa scanner?

Tags: scanner, sane, scsi

I have a problem trying to use my SCSI scanner.

I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  The scanner is an AGFA Arcus 1200, which I bought used in 2003.  It worked, and I used it regularly, for about ten years, then I stopped doing photography work for a while and the scanner hasn't even been powered up in about five years.  At this time, the scanner powers up and make its calibration sounds, but doesn't appear to be detected by the operating system.  I have the same SCSI cable and terminator that I've always used with this scanner, and my SCSI card appears in `lspci`:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD9x0/RX980 Host Bridge (rev 02)
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890S/RD990 I/O Memory Management Unit (IOMMU)
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GFX port 0)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GPP Port 0)
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GPP Port 1)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GPP Port 4)
00:0a.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GPP Port 5)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller (rev 40)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:16.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:16.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 5
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fbc (rev a1)
02:00.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VL805 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 01)
03:00.0 Serial controller: Device 1c00:3250 (rev 10)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
05:00.0 SATA controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9123 PCIe SATA 6.0 Gb/s controller (rev 11)
05:00.1 IDE interface: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE912x IDE Controller (rev 11)
06:06.0 SCSI storage controller: Adaptec AIC-7850T/7856T [AVA-2902/4/6 / AHA-2910] (rev 03)
```

`sane-find-scanner` appears to detect the scanner, but neither `simple-scan` nor `xsane` can detect the scanner.

```
$ sudo sane-find-scanner

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

found SCSI processor "Marvell 91xx Config 1.01" at /dev/sg4
  # Your SCSI scanner was detected. It may or may not be supported by SANE. Try
  # scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
  # No USB scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel driver for your USB host controller and have setup
  # the USB system correctly. See man sane-usb for details.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

I'm not really certain the device at `/dev/sd4` is my scanner; I don't recall the scanner having anything called "Marvell", and when I Google for that descriptor, it seems to be an IDE controller.

As suggested, I tried `scanimage -L`:

```
$ scanimage -L

No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

I don't know where to go from here, to check whether my scanner hardware has failed, or it's just too old for Ubuntu 16.04 to deal with (usually not a major problem -- old hardware is one of the things Ubuntu is good for).  I'm certain I've used this scanner since I switched to Linux, but it may have been under Mepis 11 or an older version of Ubuntu (Kubuntu 14.04).

Answer (score 1):

I hoped this was something simple, and it turned out to be.

A little bell went off in the back of my brain, and after resolving the "blink code" problem (I'd had the film scanning tray inserted upside down, so the calibration stripe wasn't visible to the scanner), I faintly recalled that SCSI was sensitive to startup order -- so, after powering up the scanner and letting it completely finish its warmup and calibration, I restarted the computer.

And now, `xsane` correctly detects and identifies the scanner.  Now I can scan my negatives...